# Appropriate Clustering software

Tags: music, data-visualization, clustering

I am writing my master's thesis on Music Information Retrieval and Visualisation of music collections. In order to visualise a collection of music tracks, I am looking for an appropriate (and preferably **free/open source**) clustering tool.

A functionality that is essential for my research goals is the ability to visually represent the clusters and make that visualisation interactive for the user. Examples of this interactivity could include: focus on a specific cluster, expand a cluster when clicking on it to show what's inside, show links between different tracks depending on which track is selected etc.

If the tool includes functionality to show the data in some other way except clusters (e.g. timelines, geographical map), that would be a great plus.

I hope some of you guys can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you take a look at [python](http://python.org) and [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/ecosystem.html):

- Python has a number of tools available for extracting meta data from audio files, assuming that is what you are going to cluster on, e.g. [phHachoir](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hachoir-metadata).
- Pandas provides a lot of data visualization frameworks, and can work with more, including [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/) & [plotly](https://plot.ly/) for web interfaces, there are even tools for geographic plotting.
- All the tools mentioned above are free and there is a lot of online help.